# IP Camera Test Addresses

Tags: camera, ip

I have an odd request. I recently downloaded iSpy v4.8.4.0 to begin setting up a home security network. I have yet to purchase any IP cameras because I want to start with webcams until I find better software. I want to test iSpys IP camera functions. Does anyone know where I may find IP camera addresses? Such as public places like parks, monuments, etc? Any camera to just test the programs I try.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

[Here](http://www.webcamxp.com/publicipcams.aspx) is a list of public IP cameras.

Answer (score 1):

These cameras in public places, all work in private networks so you can't access them online. Only way to reach is accessing servers or networking devices (switches, routers etc..)

You can search it online for finding someone who opened his/her camera for some purposes ( take a loot I have a wonderful sight etc..)

Comment: I've tried searching several times for publicly listed cameras with no luck. I wouldn't want to bother anyone on here with my problems before searching online.